# Make a DIV fade in, once page has loaded

Tags: jquery

Wondering how I can make the below div fade in once the page has finished loading, rather than just appearing...

So far I have:

```html
$(window).load(function() {
  
    // Sidenav show/hide JS
  
if (document.querySelector('li[title="Internal Help Centre"]')) {
    document.querySelector('#DIV_2').style.display = 'table-cell';
}
  
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style>
    #DIV_2 {display:none;}
<style>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    if ($('li[title="Internal Help Centre"]').length) {
       $('#DIV_2').fadeIn();
    }
});
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the Div display as none initially and on document ready use jquery fade in animation

CSS

```
#Div2{
    display: none
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // here you can write code for fade in Div2
});
```

Comment: The point is OP wants the code for doing a fadeIn - not just a comment saying do the code here, and what difference does changing window load to document ready make

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using: `$(window).load()`

Use: `$(document).ready()`

eg.

```
<div class="fadein" style="display:none;"></div>

<script type="type/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fadein').delay(500).fadeIn();   
})
</script>
```

You can remove the `.delay(500)` I just use it to ensure it loads after the DOM has completed loading.

Comment: so you say remove the `$(window).load` but then use delay to wait for the window to fully load?

Comment: I just use the delay to see the `fadeIn()` happen really. It is not completely necessary.

Comment: My point is it sounds like you need to learn about the difference between window load and document ready if you suggest that you add a delay to ensure that the DOM has completed loading - instead of adding a delay which may be too long / not long enough, anything that requires the DOM to fully load should be put into the window load function as this will not be fired until all elements are loaded.  document ready fires when all elements are in the dom and ready to be manipulated but may not have fully loaded eg an image will be ready but it won't have the correct dimensions until it is loaded

Comment: Granted and above duly noted. I shared what has worked for me in the past. Thought it could assist the poster as well.